# Visual Studio 2015 C# project icon options missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using MS Visual Studio Community 2015 (Update 2), I have started a C# Universal application and I want to set its icon. The information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx) states where it should be and indeed where I thought it would be, but its not.

Am I missing an intrinsic part of setting my application up?

This is what I see where I would expect to see icon options: -
[image]

(This is my first venture in C#!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process (and link) you describe is for a Windows application, not an UWP application.

See [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets) for the instructions on setting up the icon of an UWP app.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I want to stick in Windows application space as I have no need for this to scale out, the link you post talks great about design but now about how to build them in. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: I've just found the 'Visual assets' area that links to all the things in the design document yo posted, this ties it all up for me. Thank you